# Is there any way to bypass ISP-based redirection of webpages after credit finished?

Tags: internet, redirection, isp

My ISP has different Internet plans and some of them are limited traffic and once the monthly traffic has reached, any webpages will be redirected to a specific IP address showing that the credit has finished.

I’ve tried tunneling, using proxies, changing DNS server and connecting using TOR network but none of them even get connected to its server. Is there **any way** to bypass this restriction? Windows or Linux does not matter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the purpose of this question is to break the terms /contract agreement/law etc

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is there **any way** to bypass this restriction?

No you can’t. Regardless of whether you change DNS, use TOR or another virtual private network (VPN), the first “hop” in your Internet connection will *always* be a connection controlled by your Internet service provider (ISP). And if they are cutting you off, they are cutting you off.

Your account with the ISP has a device connected to it. That device has a MAC address connected to it. That MAC address has an IP address connected to it. You cannot get a new MAC or IP address without your ISP knowing it is connected to your account.

Additionally, let’s say your service is not tied to an ISP specific device and you have hard-wired connection such as cable or DSL: Then the ISP is in full control of the hard-wired connection and know who is connected to it at all times and can throttle it at will no matter what you attempt do on the client side.

So if they are throttling your connection based on your account usage, there nothing you can do other than wait for the throttle to lift or pay the ISP for more available bandwidth by either upgrading your account limit or “recharging” your account.

Comment: Just reading the subject, TOR should be able to avoid ISP-redirection to a different internet site... but the subject isn't accurate to the question, it's really "How can I use more 'internet' than my ISP allows?" in which case +1

Comment: If ISP redirects a particular website (say google) to their own server or webpage, then using TOR (assuming it connects to it's own network successfully) would bypass the ISP's "hijacking", wouldn't it? As in, your country blocks all traffic to certain sites, using TOR lets you access the blocked sites... I thought that was one of TOR's biggest "selling features"... It's even on torproject.org's "Who uses Tor?" page: *"They circumvent censorship. If you live in a country that has ever blocked Facebook or Youtube, you might need to use Tor to get basic internet functionality. "*

Comment: But like I mentioned, the question's subject was misleading, this fellow has no internet access whatsoever, no nothing will work

Comment: @JakeGould, do you mean that if i change the MAC/IP address of my router, then restriction will be removed?
@ Xen2050, as you said TOR provides only basic functionality for the internet so you really should be in a bad situation to use it. the problem is not about content blocking, it's about bypassing ISP's limitations, whether it might be so complicated or not i believe there must be a solution for that.

Comment: There is a solution, both Jake's and my answers mention one, both questions should be upvoted IMO :)

Comment: This configuration would typically be called a "walled garden" if you can to do anymore research on the topic.  Either way, your ISP controls the gateway which you must go through to access any other IP... they have control and depending on how things are connected/setup it is easy to say they may NOT even need to associate any MAC with anything as you are likely connected to a single port at your ISP.  That port is the only thing that needs to be controlled and nothing to do with end-user equipment.  All blocking/quotas could be easily implemented there.

Comment: @Xen2050 TOR can assist with consolidated "firewalls" which have a blanket coverage over a large portion of connections.  These types of firewalls are more like proxies and monitor your traffic headers.  If it sees a specific website IP as a destination then it redirects your traffic.  TOR can avoid this because it will change the destination IP and revert it back after it is beyond the firewall.  In this case, it does not matter what the destination IP as it is likely redirected at the initial gateway regardless of header information.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be clear, your ISP's internet plan only allots you so much monthly traffic, then cuts you off...

There are some easy, direct ways to bypass your ISP cutting you off from the internet:

1. Buy more internet "usage credit"/traffic from your ISP (a bigger/better plan)
2. Get a different ISP (hopefully cheaper with a bigger/better plan)

   - If you live within range of a free WiFi hotspot (a McDonalds, Starbucks,...) you might be able to use that as a temporary (or permnent?) ISP.

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand how this answer deserves to be downvoted.

Comment: @Ramhound +1 :-) Maybe it was the "cost" of the answer, or a mistake. In either case, I've added a free option

Comment: maybe it was for the same reason my question was down voted, anyway, i have no problem with the ISP or plans, it's me finishing 80G credit in 10 days.

Comment: That is a serious concern, average 8Gb/day. A lot of youtube/netflix/torrent? A "neighbour" borrowing your wifi? There are other Q's about how to find what's using all your bandwidth, best IMO would be using a router that logs traffic totals by IP/MAC, and then match up the logs to your devices. Might require firmware like Tomato/dd-wrt/openwrt...

Comment: well of course that's not something that happens every 10 days to me :) yes i use torrents a lot and actually prefer them to even high speed direct links. i have an average router but unfortunately it doesn't support third party firmwares like dd-wrt which i really like. as far as i could I took care of security settings in my router so no one else is using it. and the last thing, we're 3 who use the same internet connection.

Comment: @Xen2050 8GB/day is pretty normal.

Comment: @Navin Apparently it's not normal for Saeed, unless they only have internet access for 10 days a month, and are satisfied enough with that plan to keep it

Answer (score 5):

If I were an ISP, I would simply block all protocols that cannot be redirected (in a meaningful way) to the “Credit expired” page. Which means: Everything but DNS (used to redirect, no longer serving real IPs) and HTTP (restricted to captive portal). Accomplishing all this is trivial, too.

As such: No, you probably cannot bypass these restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Short: No you can't.

Long: Tor can help bypass ISP redirection if the redirection if you have general internet service. Most content filtering redirects are based on blacklist, the censor determines what you can't access. This is done as a blacklist because whitelist filtering is extremely expensive to maintain if you have to provide the general internet. A blacklist is much smaller and achieves most of the objective of the censor.

Usage limit quota, on the other hand, is a whitelist filter, and their whitelist is extremely small, it only allows the pages used to serve their portal and nothing else. Whitelist filter works well in this scenario because the whitelist is extremely small, the only pages that you can access is those owned by the ISPs.

The is difference is that in the former case, you do  have general internet service, while in the latter, you don't actually have an internet service. With blacklist filter, all you need to do is find a server that's not blocked and proxy your traffic through it to access the blocked content. With whitelist filter, you can only access those very small number of predetermined servers and the rest are blocked. Tor/proxies can help only when you have general internet.

You cannot bypass usage limit restriction. If you can, then I suggest you move to a different ISP as fast as possible, as that suggests total incompetence on their part. You don't know what other things they've misconfigured if they can't even implement basic usage limit properly.

I suggest you look into why you're using so much internet. Maybe a bad neighbor is "borrowing" your Wi-Fi, then you should set up Wi-Fi encryption. Maybe you're doing to much torrents, then most clients slow you to set a speed limit. Or maybe you just use a lot, in which case, you should upgrade your account to have higher bandwidth quota.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using openvpn and tunneling it over ssl. It would be slower but it works. Here is a link to help. https://www.bestvpn.com/blog/5919/how-to-hide-openvpn-traffic-an-introduction/. It is the only method that I have tried that works.

Comment: it is an option for the OP to try. He didn't mention that  the redirected page wasn't https enabled.

Comment: Thanks. but my Internet is fine now and I can't try it so I'll try it later. I don't remember whether https websites would get redirected or not. I think they only show a "time out" message instead of redirection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try scanning your ISP for any open ports (personally I would use PD-Proxy).
If you find any open ports, you can download OpenVPN and configuration files that use the required ports.

The other way is to use handlers like Psiphon handler or HTTP Injector.

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING :** We will be using VPN to connect to the internet. Some ISP don't appreciate that and might cut out your connection. **PROCEED AT YOUR OWN RISK**.

This will work only if:

1. You can ping any site.
2. (optional) You have high speed internet connection.

**Here's how it roughly works:**

When you ping a website the request passes through UDP port 53 towards DNS. In your case the webpage gets redirected, that means UDP port 53 is open.

**Why is UDP used for DNS?**

Because you can send requests even if the server doesn't exist, and you will get a simple "request timed out" if the server doesn't exist.

**Here is how it is done:**

1. Download OpenVPN for windows/linux from [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html).
2. Google for UDP port 53 OpenVPN servers.
3. Download the .ovpn config for the server which you are going to choose.
4. In OpenVPN GUI:

   - Right click on the OpenVPN GUI running in the taskbar and go to Settings.
   - Go to Proxy tab.
   - Make sure "Use OpenVPN config file settings" is selected.
5. Connect to the server using OpenVPN client running in the Taskbar.

This connection will be slightly unreliable. Here's an example:

[image: VPN Speed]

But you will be getting very high speeds. This screenshot is for my 2 Megabits/sec connection.