# Bypass "302 Found" ISP redirecton

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection, redirection, isp

I was goofing around with a usb broadband modem(sim card modem)
I used a sim card with no current subscribed data plan.On opening google.com I was redirected to the "Buy A data plan Page"(Page to buy a new subscription e.g 1500MB for $10 etc. for the purpose of this question I will use "http://isp.com/buypage" to refer to this page) 
The redirection is nothing new , it always does that when there is no data plan in use.

My growing knowledge of networking sparked curiosity. The windows tray icon for the internet connection was showing that there was an internet connection (Though not really understanding what it means, most of the time there is an internet connection it looks as shown below as it did then)

[image: Connect ICON]

So I fired up wireshark and captured the result below .
The result below is Http response of me navigating to https://google.com on my browser

Capture from wireshark as

```
Request Version: HTTP/1.1
Status Code:302
Response Phrase : Found

<html><head><title>302 Found</title></head><body><h1>302 Found</h1><p>The document has moved <a href="http://www.isp.com/buypage/">here</a></p></body></html>
```

302 **Found** is a bit *unusual* but anyway searching on how to bypass the "*302 redirects*". brought me to a firefox plugin :[NoRedirect](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noredirect/)

Configured as shown in the image.
[image: Noredirect]

Now after configuring it to that I was presented with the page as shown when trying to navigate to https://youtube.com
rather than seeing the http://isp.com/buypage

Firing up nmap(not sure why I did this): I scanned google.com
and to my amazement it worked(scan results showed up).

the folowing were the results

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-05-05 18:45 E. Africa Standard Time
NSE: Loaded 138 scripts for scanning.
NSE: Script Pre-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 18:45
Completed NSE at 18:45, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 18:45
Completed NSE at 18:45, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 18:45
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 18:45, 0.20s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 18:45
Scanning GOOGLE.COM (74.125.230.34) [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 80/tcp on 74.125.230.34
Discovered open port 443/tcp on 74.125.230.34
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 18:46, 20.88s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Initiating Service scan at 18:46
Scanning 2 services on GOOGLE.COM (74.125.230.34)
Completed Service scan at 18:46, 5.00s elapsed (2 services on 1 host)
Initiating OS detection (try #1) against GOOGLE.COM (74.125.230.34)
Initiating Traceroute at 18:46
Completed Traceroute at 18:46, 4.09s elapsed
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 18:46
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 18:46, 0.10s elapsed
NSE: Script scanning 74.125.230.34.
Initiating NSE at 18:46
Completed NSE at 18:47, 77.43s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 18:47
Completed NSE at 18:47, 0.00s elapsed
Nmap scan report for GOOGLE.COM (74.125.230.34)
Host is up (0.070s latency).
Other addresses for GOOGLE.COM (not scanned): 74.125.230.36 74.125.230.32 74.125.230.40 74.125.230.35 74.125.230.46 74.125.230.33 74.125.230.41 74.125.230.39 74.125.230.37 74.125.230.38
Not shown: 998 filtered ports
PORT    STATE SERVICE    VERSION
80/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to http://isp.com/buypage/
443/tcp open  tcpwrapped
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to http://isp.com/buypage/
Warning: OSScan results may be unreliable because we could not find at least 1 open and 1 closed port
Device type: specialized|WAP|phone
Running: iPXE 1.X, Linux 2.4.X|2.6.X, Sony Ericsson embedded
OS CPE: cpe:/o:ipxe:ipxe:1.0.0%2b cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.4.20 cpe:/o:linux:linux_kernel:2.6.22 pe:/h:sonyericsson:u8i_vivaz
OS details: iPXE 1.0.0+, Tomato 1.28 (Linux 2.4.20), Tomato firmware (Linux 2.6.22), Sony Ericsson U8i Vivaz mobile phone
Network Distance: 11 hops

TRACEROUTE (using port 80/tcp)
HOP RTT      ADDRESS
1   ... 10
11  66.00 ms 74.125.230.34

NSE: Script Post-scanning.
Initiating NSE at 18:47
Completed NSE at 18:47, 0.00s elapsed
Initiating NSE at 18:47
Completed NSE at 18:47, 0.00s elapsed
Read data files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
OS and Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at https://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 118.58 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 2132 (96.816KB) | Rcvd: 58 (3.215KB)
```

What caught my eye

```
80/tcp  open  tcpwrapped
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to http://isp.com/buypage/
443/tcp open  tcpwrapped
| http-methods: 
|_  Supported Methods: GET POST
|_http-title: Did not follow redirect to http://isp.com/buypage/
```

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to bypass this type of redirection? if so how?
  (especially since nmap **didn't follow the redirect**)
- What type of redirection technologies could they be using?

**Extra** *info*:

- The redirection is not based on DNS.
- I tried google's DNS
- I also tried IP addresses directly on the browser: same redirection
  to the "http://isp.com/buypage/"
- I have also gone through answer found in this [exchange:Is there any
  way to bypass ISP-based redirection of webpages after credit
  finished?](https://superuser.com/questions/879137/is-there-any-way-to-bypass-isp-based-redirection-of-webpages-after-credit-finish):(not helpful in mycase)
- Questions asked are for educational purposes only

Comment: I'm not sure why you feel this is different than what discussed in that "exchange:Is there any way to bypass ISP-based redirection of webpages after credit finished?" question?  Your ISP is redirecting you, only your ISP will know exactly how they're doing it, and since they control your Internet connection the only way to truly avoid it is to switch ISPs (which are the answers given in that question).  Also, it looks like you're basically just asking us to assist you in stealing internet access...?

Comment: @TECHIE007 I know how  this sounds as if my intentions are malicious, but all I want is a deeper understanding of how Nmap  _'bypassed'_ the redirection and what can be done to bypass a "302 Found" redirection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows networking icon will tell you there is an Internet connection if A) it detects an active link on the connection and B) if it's NCSI probing tests succeed ([reference](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)).

- One way that NCSI tests the Internet connection by making a DNS request to `dns.msftncsi.com` - and if it succeeds it will tell the rest of Windows that the system has Internet connectivity.
- The other way is by making an HTTP request to http://www.msftncsi.com/ncsi.txt and checking if the reply is "Microsoft NCSI".

So, it's possible and likely that:

- your ISP is allowing DNS requests to resolve normally (or intercepting the DNS request and returning an expected response to this one query only), but intercepting all other HTTP. The NCSI process above would succeed in that case.
- your ISP might be allowing traffic to the above msftncsi.com site, or possibly intercepting the request and responding responding itself, so that this is not triggered.
- your ISP is in a position to intercept ALL your traffic as it owns and operates the router your traffic is going to, so it can simply take all your HTTP requests and do anything it wants.

  - Including configuring its equipment to transparently proxy your HTTP requests and just spit out a 302 page in response if your data plan is inactive.
  - You cannot bypass a transparent proxy.
  - The 302 page does not mean there is anything behind it or that you can bypass it any way.
  - Your ISP could probably stick any HTTP response or page it wanted to in there.

The moral of the story is that you may or may not have an actual Internet connection despite what the icon says, and the 302 page is interjected by your ISP so that you one way or another end up on the ISP's buy page.

You'd be surprised at the capabilities of commercial and carrier-grade networking equipment.  Modern infrastructure equipment like newer routers can actually check for content near to the same speed as it traverses the wire and filter in real time.

Answer (score 0):

Well. I think you can actually get internet access using your ISP's webpage on an http payload and thats probably illegal but a lot of people are doing that here.